# check if string is contained within cell value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Code": [77000581079,77000458432,77000458433,77000458434,77000691973], "Description": ['16/06/2009ø01/08/2009', 'ø16/06/2009:Date Breakpoint','16/06/2009ø01/08/2009:Date Breakpoint','01/08/2009ø:Date Breakpoint','01/08/2009ø:Date Breakpoint']})
```

I want to check if `Description` contains a `str` `16/06/2009ø01/08/2009:Date Breakpoint`

If this returns `True` then I want to append `-A` to the code

Expected output :

```
    Code        Description
0   77000581079-A   16/06/2009ø01/08/2009:Date Breakpoint
1   77000458432     ø16/06/2009:Date Breakpoint
2   77000458433-A   16/06/2009ø01/08/2009:Date Breakpoint
3   77000458434     01/08/2009ø:Date Breakpoint
4   77000691973     01/08/2009ø:Date Breakpoint
```

Using :

```
for row in df['Description']:
    if df['Description'].str.contains('16/06/2009ø01/08/2009:Date Breakpoint'):
        print(row)
else:
        pass
```

I get `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`

Ive tried:

```
for row in df['Description']:
        if df['Description'].str.contains('16/06/2009ø01/08/2009:Date Breakpoint').all():
            print(row)
    else:
            pass
```

But still no Joy, ive read some docs on this error but Im abit confused about its meaning..

Is there a better way to achieve my desired outcome?

Comment: `if df['Description'].str.contains('16/06/2009ø01/08/2009:Date Breakpoint'):` will return more than one row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us try `str.contains`

```
df.Code = df.Code.astype(str)
df.loc[df.Description.str.contains('16/06/2009ø01/08/2009:Date Breakpoint'),'Code'] += '-A'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your condition like this:

```
if df['Description'].str.contains('16/06/2009ø01/08/2009:Date Breakpoint').sum() > 0:
    print(row)
```

Your condition without using `sum` will return an indicator vector so you can't directly evaluate its boolean value. It will be an array of `False`s and `True`s, so you sum it and get a positive (>0) value even if a single `True` is present in the array. This is what you get without `sum`:

```
>>> df['Description'].str.contains('16/06/2009ø01/08/2009:Date Breakpoint')
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: Description, dtype: bool
>>> df['Description'].str.contains('16/06/2009ø01/08/2009:Date Breakpoint').sum()
1
```

or just use `any`:

```
if df['Description'].str.contains('16/06/2009ø01/08/2009:Date Breakpoint').any():
    print(row)
```